# How can I fix a npm build error in Windows 11

Tags: npm, jellyfin

I am running Windows 11 and using powershell.  I tried to compile the jellyfin-web by typing
`npm ci --no-audit` and pressing enter.  I received the following errors

```
npm ERR! code EIO
npm ERR! syscal read
npm ERR! errno -4070
npm ERR! EIO; i/o error, read
```

How can I fix this error?

I looked up on the web on how to fix but it stated that I needed to change my `wsl.conf` file.  I cannot find this file anywhere on my Windows machine.

Comment: Have you tried [cleaning the cache](https://superztar.wordpress.com/2019/10/22/solving-the-npm-err-errno-4070-error-in-npm/)?

Answer (score 0):

After downgrading my version of Jellyfin I got it to work.  Thanks for your response.